# Error while saving the Message object to a local db in the onMessage method of a class which implements SessionAwareMessageListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

What I want to achieve is that whenever a message arrives from the ActiveMQ queue to the onMessage method of the class which implements SessionAwareListener I want to save it to the database.

This is how my listener class looks like

```
@Service
public class NotificationEventListener implements SessionAwareMessageListener {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationGeneratorWritePlatformService notificationGeneratorWritePlatformService;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            Notification notification = (Notification) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
            notificationGeneratorWritePlatformService.notify(
                    notification.getUserId(),
                    notification.getObjectType(),
                    notification.getObjectId(),
                    notification.getAction(),
                    notification.getActor(),
                    notification.getNotificationContent(),
                    notification.isSystemGenerated()
            );
            System.out.println("Received: " + notification.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

- The sender broadcasts the object of type **Notification**
- The notify method which is being called in the onMessage method is used to save the object of type **Notification** to the database.
- Theoretically, it should work and save the object to the database but the error logs out that the table is not present in the database.
- I have called the notify method(created by me to save the object to the database) on a random Rest request and it works perfectly there and saves the object to the database but when I use that notify method in the listener class it does not save the object and logs out that table is not present in the database.

This is my notificationContext.xml for setting up the sender and listener class.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="NotificationQueue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="notificationEventListener" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Sender class

```
@Service
public class NotificationEvent {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void broadcastNotification(final Destination destination, final Notification notification) {
        this.jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createObjectMessage(notification);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What could be the reason of table not being able to discovered in the listener class ?

Comment: I don't see how `NotificationGeneratorWritePlatformService` is configured in your post. I assumed there are some database configuration need to be injected into that service class.

Comment: Hey DJ, Should I include that class ? Actually, it just contains implementations of CRUD operations on the database.

Comment: Probably, it seems like the problem lies with Database table or configuration and the one that is using the database is your service class. So either the class or the spring configuration for that class is the culprit.

Comment: But if the problem was with the database table or configuration then it would not have worked in the another scenario too which I have mentioned. The object gets saved to the database on a Rest call. I am not able to figure out why it works there and does not work in the listener class :(